# Want to make modification on the entered URL before submit Chromium source code

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, chromium

I would like to make some modifications to the URL that user inputs in Chromium(Android) when they submit. Can you please help me point the file that handles the submitted URL in the Android Chromium source code?

Thank you

Comment: I don't do Chromium development on Android but URLs are represented as `GURL` in Chromium and the address bar is referred to as Omni box. Try setting a breakpoint here: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/omnibox/chrome_omnibox_client.cc?l=127&gs=kythe%253A%252F%252Fchromium.googlesource.com%252Fchromium%252Fsrc%253Flang%253Dc%25252B%25252B%253Fpath%253Dsrc%252Fchrome%252Fbrowser%252Fui%252Fomnibox%252Fchrome_omnibox_client.cc%2523omjYNNVwVT2nvbTJmKFhIy-CrkcSFB8SK8X92mQcfPI&gsn=GetURL&ct=xref_usages This thing is handled by browser process, so it should be easy to debug

Comment: Do you think Android Chromium project calls this C++ code or it has particular code in Java?